# Cannot run Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager 3.0 on Windows 2012

Tags: repository, nexus, sonatype

I cannot start Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager 3.0.0 Milestone 7 Release (nexus-3.0.0-b2016011501).  After unzipping the Windows archive:

then, nexus.exe /run

```
ERROR: Bundle com.sun.jna [5] Error starting mvn:net.java.dev.jna/jna/4.0.0 (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve com.sun.jna [5](R 5.0): missing requirement [com.sun.jna [5](R 5.0)] osgi.native; (|(&(osgi.native.osname~=win32)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&
... ... ... ...
(osgi.native.processor~=ppc))))]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4111)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2117)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1371)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An issue was opened here:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FELIX-5184
- https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-9787

> The error message means the OSGi framework (Apache Felix) hasn’t been able to match the OS and processor names to one of the available JNA native libraries.
>
> You should be able to workaround this by adding the following line to `NEXUS_HOME/etc/custom.properties`
>
> `felix.native.osname.alias.windowsserver2012=windows server 2012,win32`
>
> Where “win32” is the generic alias used by Felix for any Windows OS (the processor name is then used to decide whether to install a 32 or 64 bit native library).

The credit goes to *S. McCulloch* for the solution, plus *@manfred-moser* and *R. Seddon* for the quick answer from Sonatype.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out this is a bug.  See here for an explanation and a workaround:

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-9787?focusedCommentId=346263&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-346263

This will be fixed in the 3.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution to your question**

1. Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager 3.0.0 Milestone 7 Release requires a Java 8 Runtime Environment (JRE) from Oracle. The distributions for OSX and Windows include suitable runtime environments for the specific operating system.
2. Please confirm you have installed Java by performing this command.

> $  java -version 
> java version "1.8.0_60" Java(TM) SE Runtime
>   Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
>   (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)

3. Please find the description [Link](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/install.html#_java_runtime_environment) here

Comment: I do have Java 8 installed: C:\>java -version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b18, mixed mode).   I have no problem running nexus-2.12.

Comment: Set the path accordingly,  your issue will be resolved :-)

Comment: I have it in my path

Comment: Please check if nexus is pointing to your correct jdk version.  If yes, restart the nexus. Hope should work.

Comment: Are you running the same Nexus version?

Comment: Nope, I worked on earlier versions of nexus. Nexus unable to start exceptions would be mainly due to jdk classpath issues.  That's why I suggested to check the correctness of the path.

Comment: @Jeff, Please remove the older version of nexus-2.12 from your Path variable and point to the Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager 3.0.0 Milestone 7 Release (which you have mentioned). Restart your nexus.

Comment: @jeff, what is your operating system? For me it works out of the box in Windows 7. But it failed in two of my Windows Server 2012 machines.

Comment: @ Rafael,  that might be due multiple path settings pointing to different jdk versions.  Ensure you only jdk 8 version in your windows server 2012. Please check you have set the environment variable for this nexus version.

Comment: @rafaelrezend - you hit the nail right on the head.  The servers I was trying it on are Windows 2012 machines.  I tried it on a Windows 7 machine and it ran fine.  If you create a separate answer, i'll accept it as the solution.  This looks like a bug in Nexus 3 Milestone 7. Thanks!

Comment: I edited the subject to include "Windows 2012" to make it easier for other people encountering the same issue.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, I had a fresh install of Windows 2012. I tried first with the bundled Java from Nexus. Later, I tried with an installation from Oracle. No success. So, I believe the problem is not with java or environment variables.

Comment: @jersey-city-ninja, just contacted Sonatype. I'll see what they say about it.

Comment: @ Rafael, many thanks for your support.  Would be great learning curve of everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in version **3.37.1-01** and fixed it by changing the following :

**application-port** to **8085**

in the file **etc\nexus-default.properties**