# Unable to resolve com.sun.jna when running Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager 3.6 on Linux for ARM architecture

Tags: repository, nexus, sonatype

The following error appears after extracting the Linux archive (`nexus-3.6.2-01-unix.tar.gz`)

then, `nexus run`

```
ERROR: Bundle com.sun.jna [9] Error starting reference:file:system/net/java/dev/jna/jna/4.1.0/jna-4.1.0.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve com.sun.jna [9](R 9.0): missing requirement [com.sun.jna [9](R 9.0)] osgi.native; (|(&(osgi.native.osname~=win32)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=win32)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=wince)(osgi.native.processor~=arm))(&(osgi.native.osname~=sunos)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=sunos)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=sunos)(osgi.native.processor~=sparc))(&(osgi.native.osname~=sunos)(osgi.native.processor~=sparcv9))(&(osgi.native.osname~=aix)(osgi.native.processor~=ppc))(&(osgi.native.osname~=aix)(osgi.native.processor~=ppc64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=ppc))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=ppc64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=arm))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=ia64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=freebsd)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=freebsd)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=openbsd)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=openbsd)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=macosx)(|(osgi.native.processor~=x86)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64)(osgi.native.processor~=ppc)))) Unresolved requirements: [[com.sun.jna [9](R 9.0)] osgi.native; (|(&(osgi.native.osname~=win32)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=win32)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=wince)(osgi.native.processor~=arm))(&(osgi.native.osname~=sunos)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=sunos)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=sunos)(osgi.native.processor~=sparc))(&(osgi.native.osname~=sunos)(osgi.native.processor~=sparcv9))(&(osgi.native.osname~=aix)(osgi.native.processor~=ppc))(&(osgi.native.osname~=aix)(osgi.native.processor~=ppc64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=ppc))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=ppc64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=arm))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=ia64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=freebsd)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=freebsd)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=openbsd)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=openbsd)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=macosx)(|(osgi.native.processor~=x86)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64)(osgi.native.processor~=ppc))))])
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve com.sun.jna [9](R 9.0): missing requirement [com.sun.jna [9](R 9.0)] osgi.native; (|(&(osgi.native.osname~=win32)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=win32)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=wince)(osgi.native.processor~=arm))(&(osgi.native.osname~=sunos)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=sunos)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=sunos)(osgi.native.processor~=sparc))(&(osgi.native.osname~=sunos)(osgi.native.processor~=sparcv9))(&(osgi.native.osname~=aix)(osgi.native.processor~=ppc))(&(osgi.native.osname~=aix)(osgi.native.processor~=ppc64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=ppc))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=ppc64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=arm))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=ia64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=freebsd)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=freebsd)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=openbsd)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=openbsd)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=macosx)(|(osgi.native.processor~=x86)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64)(osgi.native.processor~=ppc)))) Unresolved requirements: [[com.sun.jna [9](R 9.0)] osgi.native; (|(&(osgi.native.osname~=win32)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=win32)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=wince)(osgi.native.processor~=arm))(&(osgi.native.osname~=sunos)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=sunos)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=sunos)(osgi.native.processor~=sparc))(&(osgi.native.osname~=sunos)(osgi.native.processor~=sparcv9))(&(osgi.native.osname~=aix)(osgi.native.processor~=ppc))(&(osgi.native.osname~=aix)(osgi.native.processor~=ppc64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=ppc))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=ppc64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=arm))(&(osgi.native.osname~=linux)(osgi.native.processor~=ia64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=freebsd)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=freebsd)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=openbsd)(osgi.native.processor~=x86))(&(osgi.native.osname~=openbsd)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64))(&(osgi.native.osname~=macosx)(|(osgi.native.processor~=x86)(osgi.native.processor~=x86-64)(osgi.native.processor~=ppc))))]
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4132)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2117)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1371)
at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:308)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Despite the error, from a quick test, nexus appears to run normally. However, a solution or a workaround for the error would be very welcome.

Nexus Version: Sonatype Nexus OSS 3.6.2-01

System info

```
uname -a
Linux arm-host 3.14.79-27-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jul 10 19:29:37 MDT 2017 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

Java version

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_152"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.152-b16, mixed mode)
```

Related post: [Cannot run Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager 3.0 on Windows 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35163442/cannot-run-sonatype-nexus-repository-manager-3-0-on-windows-2012)

An issue was opened here:

- https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-15107

Answer (score -1):

After testing the latest version of the Linux archive (nexus-3.10.0-04-unix.tar.gz) I can no longer reproduce the issue, therefore it has been resolved.